# Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality - How can you divine the linchpin of $\Vert proj_{W}\mathbf{v}\Vert$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, intuition, visualization

Source: [*Linear Algebra*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321385179) by Lay (4 edn 2011). p. 379. Section 6.7. Theorem 16.

> [image]
>
> If $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$, then the inequality becomes $ 0 \le 0 $, which is true. See Practice Problem 6.7.1 on p. 382.
>
> If $\mathbf{u}\neq \mathbf{0}$, let $W$ be the subspace spanned by $\mathbf{u}$.

$1.$ How can you divine to define $W$ like this? I'm not clairvoyant enough to spot this  flash of genius.

> $$
> \Vert proj_{W}\mathbf{v}\Vert=\Vert\frac{\langle v,u\rangle}{\langle u,u\rangle}u\Vert=\frac{|\langle v,u\rangle|}{|\langle u,u\rangle|}\Vert u\Vert=\frac{|\langle v,u\rangle|}{||u||^{2}}\Vert u\Vert=\frac{|\langle u,v\rangle|}{\Vert u\Vert}
> $$
>   Since $\Vert proj_{W}\mathbf{v}\Vert^2 \leq\Vert v\Vert^2 \implies \Vert proj_{W}v\Vert\leq\Vert v\Vert$, so $\displaystyle \frac{|\langle u,v\rangle|}{\Vert u\Vert}\leq\Vert v\Vert$.

$2.$ How can you divine this proof's linchpin: computing $\Vert proj_{W}v\Vert$?

Comment: Yes, it could be spanned by $\;v\;$ reversing the roles of each in the proof... The real secret here is to know the basic properties of the (orthogonal) projection of a vector onto some subspace...

Comment: As for 1. the statement is symmetric in $u$ and $v$, you could of course do the same reasoning with $v$ instead of $u$, if $v\ne 0$. I don't get what you are asking in 2.

Comment: @Thomas: Thanks for your comment. The key step in the proof is to compute $\Vert proj_{W}v\Vert$, right? I'm asking from where this key step originates? To me, $\Vert proj_{W}v\Vert$ just appeared "sibyllinely."

Comment: Geometric intuiotion, I guess. It behaves similarly in Euclidean three space, so I guess people simply tried to carry that over.

Comment: The key point is the right angle between $u$ and $v-proj_Wv$ that is there by the definition of orthogonal projection. Then for any other multiple $\tilde u$ of $u$, $$\|v-\tilde u\|^2=\|v-proj_Wv\|^2+\|proj_Wv-\tilde u\|^2,$$ so that $proj_Wv$ really minimizes the distance. One can also just start with the minimal distance property as definition of projection as in my answer and get the orthogonality of the projection as a corollary.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the geometric interpretation of the usual proof. The line in direction $\mathbf u$ is parametrized as $$W=\{t \mathbf u:t\in\Bbb R\},$$ the projection $P_W(\mathbf v)$ is the point of minimal distance $\|\mathbf v-t\mathbf u\|$ from $\mathbf v$ to a point on the line $W$, so
$$
P_W(\mathbf v)
=\arg\min\{ \|\mathbf w-\mathbf v\|:\mathbf w\in W\}
=\arg\min\{\|t\mathbf u-\mathbf v\|:t\in\Bbb R\}\cdot \mathbf u,
$$
 this distance becomes minimal if the square of it is minimal, the square is a quadratic polynomial in $t$
$$
\|\mathbf v-t\mathbf u\|^2
=\|\mathbf v\|^2-2t\,\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle +t^2\,\|\mathbf u\|^2
$$
and the minimal point of this parabola can be determined in different ways.

For instance by completing the square one obtains
$$
0\le \|\mathbf u\|^2\,\|\mathbf v-t\mathbf u\|^2
= \|\mathbf u\|^2\,\|\mathbf v\|^2-\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle^2+(t\|\mathbf u\|^2-\langle \mathbf u,\mathbf v\rangle)^2
$$
which gives the minimizer $t$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality at the same time.

---

**Specifically to the questions:**

1. *Why this line and the projection:* This is just the way this proof works. It has the additional advantage that it is easily extendable to general Hilbert spaces. One could also do a non-geometrical, purely analytical proof in the fashion the general Hölder inequality, of which Cauchy-Schwarz is a special case, is proved.
2. *What is projection:* In the case of normed spaces the point of least distance, as used above. There is also central projection as in photography which is only loosely related to this kind of projection.

---

**Another answer to 2):** Assume $u\ne 0$. Then the space can be divided up into a family of planes $$E_d=\{\mathbf v:⟨\mathbf u,\mathbf v⟩=d\}.$$ The point on the line $W$ through $\mathbf u$ that is on the plane is $\mathbf u_d=\frac{d}{\|\mathbf u\|^2}\mathbf u$. By construction, $\mathbf u$ is the normal of the plane $E_d$, i.e., the plane is perpendicular to the line $W$.

Thus under orthogonal projection all points in $E_d$ get mapped to $\mathbf u_d$. Eliminating $d$ from this relation results in
$$
\operatorname{proj}_W \mathbf v =\frac{⟨\mathbf u,\mathbf v⟩}{\|\mathbf u\|^2}\mathbf u
$$

Comment: Thank you. You wrote $t\mathbf{u}$ but my question doesn't contain this. What does it mean? Also, would you please elucidate how your answer resolves my two questions? You write about "minimal distance", but from where to where? Will you please to respond in your answer, and not as comments?

Comment: @LePressentiment: Done. The parametrization of a line through the origin is familiar?

Comment: +1. Thank you very much again. Yes. Regarding question #2, I'm not asking about the definition of $proj$ or what it is, but rather how one wuold divine to start the proof with this? This key step feels "sibylline"? Did you intend your answer to attend to this?